# SwiftData model not updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, model, swift-data

I have a problem with the SwiftData model not updating properly when changing some its child property's property. haha.. I know :)

Let me provide some code samples so you can understand my problem.
I have the following models:

```
@Model
final class Exercise {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \WorkoutExercise.exercise)
    var exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = [WorkoutExercise]()
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), title: String = "", exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.exercises = exercises
    }
}
```

```
@Model
final class Workout {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \WorkoutExercise.workout)
    var exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = [WorkoutExercise]()
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), title: String = "", exercises: [WorkoutExercise] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.exercises = exercises
    }
}

extension Workout {
    @Transient
    var subtitle: String {
        let exerciseTitles = self.exercises
            .compactMap { $0.title.lowercased() }
            .joined(separator: ", ")
        
        return exercises.isEmpty ? "No exercises" : exerciseTitles
    }
}
```

```
@Model
final class WorkoutExercise {
    var id: UUID
    var exercise: Exercise?
    var workout: Workout?
    var sets: [ExerciseSet] = [ExerciseSet]()
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), exercise: Exercise, sets: [ExerciseSet] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.exercise = exercise
        self.sets = sets
    }
}

extension WorkoutExercise {
    @Transient
    var title: String {
        exercise?.title ?? "Empty"
    }
}
```

```
struct ExerciseSet: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var rest: Int
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), weight: Int, reps: Int, rest: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.weight = weight
        self.reps = reps
        self.rest = rest
    }
}
```

Long story short, I separated the `Exercise` from `Workout` by using `WorkoutExercise` so I can create multiple workouts using the same exercise (`Exercise`) while each of these exercises (`WorkoutExercise`) has its own implementation using its own sets (`ExerciseSet`). I want somehow to use then `Exercise` type to create some statistics based on its exercises (`WorkoutExercise`).

My problem is that when I want to edit an `WorkoutExercise` title, I am actually gonna edit its `exercise: Exercise?` title instead in order to update the title in all workouts workouts that includes the exercise I edited. But somehow this change is not updating the whole UI instantly, but only after I restart the app.
As far as I can tell, the `subtitle` `Workout` property is not correctly updating.

Here is how I am displaying the workouts.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Query(sort: \Workout.title, order: .forward) private var workouts: [Workout]
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                    Section {
                        WorkoutListItem(workout: workout)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Workouts")
            .scrollDisabled(workouts.isEmpty)
            .listSectionSpacing(.compact)
            .navigationDestination(for: Workout.self) { workout in
                WorkoutDetailView(workout: workout)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct WorkoutListItem: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    private var workout: Workout
    
    init(workout: Workout) {
        self.workout = workout
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: workout) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(workout.title)
                    .font(.title3.bold())
                Divider()
                Text(workout.subtitle)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .italic()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct WorkoutDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    private var workout: Workout
    
    init(workout: Workout) {
        self.workout = workout
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(workout.exercises) { exercise in
                    Text(exercise.title)
                }
            } header: {
                Text("Exercises")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(workout.title)
        .navigationDestination(for: WorkoutExercise.self) { exercise in
            EditWorkoutExerciseView(exercise: exercise)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I edit the `WorkoutExercise`.
The update

```
struct EditWorkoutExerciseView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var exercise: WorkoutExercise
    
    @State private var title: String = ""
        
    init(exercise: WorkoutExercise) {
        self.exercise = exercise
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField(exercise.title.isEmpty ? "Enter title here..." : exercise.title, text: $title)
            } header: {
                Text("Exercise Title")
            } footer: {
                Text("This title will be updated in all workouts that include this exercise.")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Exercise")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                Button {
                    update()
                
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func update() {
        guard let exerciseToEdit = exercise.exercise else { return }
        
        if !title.isEmpty {
            exerciseToEdit.title = title
        }
                
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the updated exercise title inside the `WorkoutDetailView` is displayed correctly, but the subtitle is not updating inside the `WorkoutListItem`, so in the `ContentView` list also.

Can anyone explain to me why does this happen?

Comment: I found out that when updating the title and saving the context, the `WorkoutListItem` init is called again, but the body does not update at all even though it contains the subtitle (which I printed on init so I can see it updates and it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a solution for this problem I managed to do as below.

Create an `@Observable` class that wraps the `Workout` type and use this class type in the view.

```
@Observable
class WorkoutModel {
    var workout: Workout

    init(workout: Workout) {
        self.workout = workout
    }
}

struct WorkoutListItem: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    private var workout: WorkoutModel
    
    init(workout: Workout) {
        self.workout = WorkoutModel(workout: workout)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: workout) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(workout.title)
                    .font(.title3.bold())
                Divider()
                Text(workout.subtitle)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .italic()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If any of you have any other better solutions or an improvement for this one, I am more than grateful to hear about them.

Comment: Did you stick with this? I'm having a similar issue - updating a detail view with it open, and using an API call to update the viewed model leads to the view remaining stale.

Comment: Yes, I did stick with the above solution. I am not sure why the view does not rerender automatically without this approach.